Meeting on a grid
Alan is sitting at $ (0, 0) $ and Barbara is sitting at $ (4, 4) $. Each minute, Alan moves up or to the right one unit with equal probability, unless he is on the border of the $ 4 \times 4 $ grid centered at $ (2, 2) $, in which case he moves in the only possible direction that keeps him within range. Barbara behaves similarly, but moves down or to the left instead. What is the probability that the two meet before they reach the opposite corner?
I want to find the probability Alan and Barbara meet at each point on the diagonal. Take for example the probability they meet at $(0,4)$. I thought that probability would be $$\frac{1}{{8 \choose 4}} \times \frac{1}{{8 \choose 4}}$$ since there are ${8 \choose 4}$ total paths for each of Alan and Barbara and only one way to get to $(0,4)$. However, the solution instead says this probability is $$\frac{1}{2^4} \times \frac{1}{2^4}$$ Which also makes sense to me, but it's a different answer from mine. Can someone explain this?
I already saw Explanation needed for why my solution is incorrect. but that doesn't make sense to me because we know Alan and Barbara must remain within the bounds of the grid.
The more I think about it, I think the solution given to me is in fact false and solves for the case where Alan and Barbara are not constrained to the board. I think if they're constrained to the board, my solution is right. But not sure.

In short, your error is assuming that all $\binom{8}{4}$ paths are equally likely.  They aren't.  The irony is that this fact follows precisely from the assumption that the two are constrained to the square (which you had thought was the reason the other solution was erroneous).
For instance, the path that goes through $(4,0)$, for Alan, must go right for the first four steps, each of which are independent of the others, and each of probability $1/2$ (since he could have gone up at each step).  Then his last four steps necessarily go up.  It follows that this path has probability $1/2^4$.
On the other hand, the path that alternates right, up, right, up, ... until Alan reaches $(4,4)$ has seven steps that are random before the last step is forced to go up.  That means this path has probability $1/2^7$ of being the one Alan uses.
The paths aren't equally likely, so we cannot find the probability by simply counting paths.

The nice feature of the problem that allows the solution to look like we're ignoring the boundary is that the two must meet on the diagonal $x+y=4$, and before this line, neither Alan nor Barbara will have met the opposite sides.  That means each of the moves they'll have made by the time they could meet will have probability $1/2$ (up/right or down/left).

Alan has $4$ independent choices to go up or to the right prior to reaching the diagonal $x + y = 4$, so there are $2^4$ possible paths he can take. If we let $k$ measure the number of horizontal steps, this is just a restatement of the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{4}{k} = 2^4. 
$$
How many of these paths culminate at the point $(0, 4)$? The answer is unsurprisingly $\binom{4}{0} = 1$.
Hence, he has a $\smash{\frac{1}{2^4}}$ probability of reaching that point on the diagonal.
By symmetry, Barb has the same probability of reaching this point, starting from the opposite corner. If we like, we can let $k$ denote the number of steps downward that she takes, and the argument is completely analogous. Thus, the probability that they meet at that point is
$$
\frac{1}{(2^4)^2} = \frac{1}{2^8} = \frac{1}{256}. 
$$
For the general case, for any $0 \leq k \leq 4$, the probability that either  reaches the diagonal at the spot $(k, 4 - k)$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2^4}\binom{4}{k}, 
$$
so the probability that they both reach the same spot is its square:
$$
\frac{1}{2^8}\binom{4}{k}^{\!2}. 
$$
These probabilities are
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
P(k) & \frac{1}{256} & \frac{16}{256} & \frac{36}{256} & \frac{16}{256} & \frac{1}{256} 
\end{array} 
$$

+1 : also, nice answer.  You might also mention that (in general) $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \left[ ~\binom{n}{k}^2 ~\right] = \binom{2n}{n}.$$  So, the computations can be shortcutted to $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{8}{4}}{2^8}.$

The sum of coordinates $(x+y)$ for Alan starts from $0$ and increases by one in each step; at the same time, the sum for Barbara decreases from $8$ by one. It follows they can meet on the diagonal only, where and when both have $x+y=4$. So you only need to calculate meeting probabilities for $(0,4), (1,3), (2,2)$. Thanks to symmetry probabilities for $(3,1)$ and $(4,0)$ equal those for $(1,3)$ and $(0,4)$, respectively, and all remaining points yield zero chance for $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ to meet.
The two may meet at any of those points iff they both (independently) choose a path to that point, so the probability of meeting at any chosen point $X$ is a product of probabilities that $\text{A}$ comes to $X$ and $\text{B}$ comes to $X$.
If you tilt the graph a bit, you may notice that the drawing of routes from $(0,0)$ and from $(4,4)$ to the diagonal resembles that of Pascal's triangle—and the Pascal triangle's numbers are precisely numbers of paths available to Alan and Barbara to arrive at respective points of the grid.
The rest of the solution is just boring arithmetics.

Thank you, @Bml, for fixing all my typos. :)

You're welcome :-)
